# Changing JFIF X and Y Resolution with Java

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I have a JPEG image that need to set Metadata JFIF X and Y Resolution, but I don't know how I can do it. Please be Aware I don't need set Image Vertical and Horizental resolution! I need added Into JFIF X and Y Resolution as dot with Java. Some Extracted Meta Info :

```
[JPEG] Compression Type - Baseline
[JPEG] Data Precision - 8 bits
[JPEG] Image Height - 2867 pixels
[JPEG] Image Width - 4448 pixels
[JPEG] Number of Components - 3
[JPEG] Component 1 - Y component: Quantization table 0, Sampling factors 2 horiz/2 vert
[JPEG] Component 2 - Cb component: Quantization table 1, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert
[JPEG] Component 3 - Cr component: Quantization table 1, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert
[JFIF] Version - 1.1
[JFIF] Resolution Units - inch
[JFIF] X Resolution - 32 dots  <------Here What I need to Change
[JFIF] Y Resolution - 32 dots  <------Here What I need to Change
[JFIF] Thumbnail Width Pixels - 0
[JFIF] Thumbnail Height Pixels - 0
[Huffman] Number of Tables - 4 Huffman tables
[File Type] Detected File Type Name - JPEG
[File Type] Detected File Type Long Name - Joint Photographic Experts Group
[File Type] Detected MIME Type - image/jpeg
[File Type] Expected File Name Extension - jpg
[File] File Name - project-desk-26a124af27488a761b7a7b8b636500bc (1).jpg
[File] File Size - 1325321 bytes
[File] File Modified Date - Mon Oct 30 06:02:48 +03:30 2023

--------------------------------------------------------
```

[More Example for read metadata At here,](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/wiki/SampleOutput) but no edit meta data!